# make columns out of strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, analytics

Trying to make columns with values of 1 and 2 (true, false) out of not good column!
I found a laborious way by checking via the `contains` method and imputing values one by one, but I would rather loop over them!

My data:

```
df['activities']

0                                                                    Game | jogging  | self teaching
1                                        Game | outside food  | junk food  | with GF | self teaching
2                                                    Game | outside food  | jogging  | self teaching
3                                                      outside food  | fab | with GF | self teaching
4       eating in restaurant | drinking  | Game | outside food  | with GF | jogging  | self teaching
```

The only good way was this but lots of labor !

```
df["Working out"]=df["activities"].str.contains("jogging |indoor workout |gym ")
```

I tried to clean, split and loop over the data but it yields the wrong answers:

```
df["activities"]=df["activities"].str.replace("|","",regex=True)
df["activities"]=df["activities"].str.split("  ")
activities=[]
for act in df["activities"]:
    if act not in activities:
        activities.append(act)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'activities': [
        'Game | jogging | self teaching',
        'Game | outside food | junk food | with GF | self teaching',
        'Game | outside food | jogging | self teaching',
        'outside food | fab | with GF | self teaching',
        'eating in restaurant | drinking | Game | outside food | with GF | jogging | self teaching'
    ]
})


df['activities'] = df['activities'].str.lower().str.strip()


df_activities = df['activities'].str.split(' \| ', expand=True).stack().str.strip().reset_index()

unique_activities = df_activities[0].unique()


for activity in unique_activities:
    df[activity] = df['activities'].str.contains(activity).map({True: 1, False: 2})

print(df)
```

[image]